# Elasticsearch completion suggester with standard analyzer and numbers

Tags: elasticsearch

I get an error when trying to index numbers on a completion field with the standard analyser.

Mapping:

```
PUT music
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Indexing:

```
PUT music/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "suggest" : [ 1234, 5678 ]
}
```

This is the error I get:

`[parsing_exception] failed to parse [null]: expected text or object, but got VALUE_NUMBER`

Do I have to input strings?

Comment: number values won't be analyzed, unless they are strings (text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to put your numbers in double quotes (i.e. as strings)

```
PUT music/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "suggest" : [ "1234", "5678" ]
                ^    ^  ^    ^
                |    |  |    |
                 here and here
}
```